# Issue adding in external graphics

Tags: graphics

file structure is

```
 someDirectory
 someDirectory/Images
```

The code in question is as follows

```
 \graphicspath{/home/LaTeX Musings/Whitepaper Template/Images}

 \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/Images/mistake.jpg}
    \caption{A cat.}
    \label{fig:cat}
 \end{figure}
```

The line with includegraphics is the one erroring out it is line 77 in the following error I think I am not telling it how to find my directory with the images

error is

```
 ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `mistake.jpg' not found: using draft setting.
```

any ideas thanks guys new to LaTeX

Comment: Use `\graphicspath`

Comment: Which OS are you using? On Linux, `/Images` is different of `Images`: the first is not sub-folder of any other folder; the last is folder inside the current folder.

Comment: @JarioADelRio I tried that still getting the error will update

Comment: @KyleSponable, if you use `graphicspath` don't write folders in the argument of `\includegraphics`.

Comment: its best to avoid spaces in directory names, but also if your document is in `/home/LaTeX Musings/Whitepaper Template`  then don't put that in the graphics path, just use `\includegraphics{Images/mistake.jpg}`  (no leading `/`)